# Git-annex link to different file names

Tags: git, git-annex

Maybe this is just a crazy use case that doesn't work, but I was wondering if there's a way to build a file's history from files with different file names. I'm exploring this idea because I'd like to have a git-annex system but I can't force my coworkers to adapt.

Here's what I have in mind :

> Folder 1, managed by coworkers (On a shared disk) :
>
> - drawing_shop_12_nov_2015.pdf
> - drawing_shop_13_nov_2015.pdf
> - drawing_asbuilt_14_nov_2015.pdf
> - drawing_asbuilt_rev1_15_nov_2015.pdf

And

> Git-annex, managed by me :
>
> - drawing.pdf
>
> (with a *shop* branch and a *asbuilt* branch)

The git-annex's `drawing.pdf` would have an history like this :

```
[shop]
|
Commit A "Initial shop drawing"
|
Commit B "Add corrections from Wizzbasket"
 \
  |
  [asbuilt]
  Commit C "Reflect as built"
  |
  Commit D "Change dweezelbox block for simplicity"
```

But somehow the "managed by coworkers" repo would be a direct mode repo with `Commit A` pointing to `drawing_shop_12_nov_2015.pdf`, `Commit B` to `drawing_shop_13_nov_2015.pdf` etc.

Can this be done?